Datadog Trace Headers Sent with Fetch but not Angular HttpClient
What's Working:
I have a web application. It has an Angular (version 14) client-side and Play framework server-side. I have followed the directions in Datadog's documentation for connecting RUM and traces. The end-to-end trace is working (with the relevant X-Datadog-* headers being sent) for the requests made via the fetch function (located in node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts).
What's Not Working:
But the majority of the requests the Angular app makes to my server are via the HttpClient in node_modules/@angular/common/http/index.d.ts. None of those requests are being traced end-to-end because the relevant X-Datadog-* headers are not being injected in them. I also have some HttpInterceptors, so I thought perhaps one of them might be stripping out these headers. But the X-Datadog-* headers never seem to have been injected at all (they're never present even at the beginning of any interceptor's intercept function).
Attempted Solutions:
I'm guessing perhaps the Datadog RUM SDK's header-injection logic and Angular HttpClient's dealing with requests' headers are conflicting somehow. But I don't know how to fix it. I've tried with @datadog/browser-rum versions 5.13.0 and 5.15.0. I've also tried doing datadogRum.init() as the first thing in main.ts as well as in the ngOnInit() function of app.component.ts.
